# Drupal 7 views filter content by owner on/off checkbox

Tags: views

I create View with [Leaflet map](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet), I have filters content by taxonomy terms (checkboxes), but I can't figure out how to create on/off checkbox content filter by the owner to show only own added content. Does anyone have any experience of creating such type of filter?

[image]